# How to properly compile Synergy on Linux Mint?

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake, linux-mint

I've tried to follow the instructions detailed in the [documentation](https://github.com/symless/synergy-core/wiki/Compiling#Ubuntu_1004_to_1510). However, every time I use `Make`, I get this error:

```
CMake Warning at cmake/Version.cmake:27 (message):
  Synergy version wasn't set.  Set to 2.0.0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (include)


-- Full Synergy version string is '2.0.0-snapshot.b1-1cf3baed'
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sszebrat/synergy-core/build
[  2%] Built target common
[ 13%] Built target arch
[ 22%] Built target base
[ 24%] Built target shared
[ 27%] Built target io
[ 30%] Built target mt
[ 36%] Built target net
[ 46%] Built target server
[ 54%] Built target platform
[ 55%] Built target client
[ 79%] Built target core
[ 80%] Built target synergy-core
[ 81%] Built target synergyc
[ 82%] Built target synergys
[ 83%] Built target gmock
[ 84%] Built target gtest
[ 85%] Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/integtests
../../lib/arch/libarch.a(ArchInternetUnix.cpp.o): In function `CurlFacade::CurlFacade()':
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x212): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
../../lib/arch/libarch.a(ArchInternetUnix.cpp.o): In function `CurlFacade::~CurlFacade()':
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x34b): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x350): undefined reference to `curl_global_cleanup'
../../lib/arch/libarch.a(ArchInternetUnix.cpp.o): In function `CurlFacade::get(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x3b4): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x3d7): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x47a): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x4bb): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x4cd): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x4ed): undefined reference to `curl_easy_strerror'
../../lib/arch/libarch.a(ArchInternetUnix.cpp.o): In function `CurlFacade::urlEncode(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x69a): undefined reference to `curl_easy_escape'
ArchInternetUnix.cpp:(.text+0x753): undefined reference to `curl_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/test/integtests/CMakeFiles/integtests.dir/build.make:299: recipe for target 'bin/integtests' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/integtests] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1089: recipe for target 'src/test/integtests/CMakeFiles/integtests.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/test/integtests/CMakeFiles/integtests.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried fixing it by adding this line to Cmakelists.txt:

```
link_libraries(libcurl)
```

but that just causes a different error:

```
[  2%] Built target common
[ 13%] Built target arch
[ 22%] Built target base
[ 24%] Built target shared
[ 27%] Built target io
[ 30%] Built target mt
[ 36%] Built target net
[ 46%] Built target server
[ 54%] Built target platform
[ 55%] Built target client
[ 79%] Built target core
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/synergy-core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcurl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/cmd/core/CMakeFiles/synergy-core.dir/build.make:115: recipe for target 'bin/synergy-core' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/synergy-core] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:802: recipe for target 'src/cmd/core/CMakeFiles/synergy-core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/cmd/core/CMakeFiles/synergy-core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know **how can I fix this error and compile synergy?**

Comment: Do you really need to compile it for contribution, or is it just to use synergy? Because there's actually a package for [synergy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=synergy) in aptitude that would require less work

Comment: I saw that package, but unfortunately it's outdated. And yes, it is because I want to use it. It's pretty expensive for me to buy the binaries...

Comment: Which version of synergy are you looking for? There's a PPA for [v1.8.8](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/xenial/apps/getdeb/synergy), also is your system 64bits or 32bits?

Comment: I'm looking for version 2.0, and it's a 64-bit system.

Comment: Hmmm... it's working for me under Archlinux, it compiles properly, looks like your missing a library, can you update your question's description and add all the command you've done to achieve this?

Comment: I followed the exact instructions listed under the wiki page I linked under "Linux" at the end of the page.

Comment: did the solution worked?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing libcurl library, try installing it with `apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev` then you should be able to compile the project

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcurl`

CMake can't find the library on your system. Under Linux library are often installed under the system rather than in the project like windows.